# How to await multiple threads completing?

Tags: c#, windows, multithreading

Now, I have function working well like this.

```
StartWorking() {
    mThread = new Thread(fooFunction);
    mMonitorThread = new Thread(MonitoringThreadFunction);

    mThread.Start();
    mMonitorintThread.Start();    
}
```

Now, I need add a loog for this code. Letting it run several times in a row. Sequentially.
I tried do this. But it is messed up. Thread's work is not working right.

```
StartWorking()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        mThread = new Thread(fooFunction);
        mMonitorThread = new Thread(MonitoringThreadFunction);

        mThread.Start();
        mMonitorintThread.Start();
    }
}
```

So, what should I do for my purporse?

Comment: Why would you want to have your thread run three separate times?  If you've got a task that you want to run asynchronously and it has 3 stages run them all in the same child thread before returning.  If you have 3 different tasks to run, why not just spawn 3 separate worker threads and be done with it?

Comment: @rie819, coz I have t run this repeated hundreds time. So...

Comment: Please do a better job formatting your question in future.  For more information, see the [faq#howtoask].

Comment: @AndersLind Saying you have to run it hundreds of times, doesn't tell me the type of task your trying to perform.  I just don't see why you'd need to spawn these threads in a for loop.  But if you want to be that guarded with your purpose, I wont be able to potentially offer a suggestion on how to improve your design.

Comment: My *guess* (and the assumption in my answer) was that the goal was to run "fooFunction" and "MonitoringThreadFunction" in parallel, but not start the next iteration until both complete...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
mThread.Join();
mMonitorThread.Join();
```

or, if you're on .NET ≥ 4, use `System.Threading.CountdownEvent` with InitialCount = 2 and pass it in the `Thread.Start()` method.

Edit: yet, the TPL solution is definitely cleaner.

Answer (score 3):

> Letting it run several times in a row. Sequentially.

If you're trying to run the code *sequentially*, threading may be inappropriate.  At the least, you'd need to start the two worker threads, then wait on them to complete.

This could be done, in your code, via adding calls to `Join()`, ie:

```
 StartWorking()
 {
     for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
     {
       mThread = new Thread(fooFunction);
       mMonitorThread = new Thread(MonitoringThreadFunction);

       mThread.Start();
       mMonitorintThread.Start();

       // Wait for these to finish before starting another loop
       mThread.Join();
       mMonitorintThread.Join();
     }

 }
```

However, I would recommend considering switching this to using the TPL, instead.  The syntax is much cleaner, IMO:

```
 StartWorking()
 {
     for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
     {
        Parallel.Invoke(
           () => fooFunction(),
           () => MonitoringThreadFunction() 
        );
     }
 }
```

In addition, this will take advantage of the ThreadPool instead of firing up a new thread each time, which is likely going to be more efficient.  (It will also potentially reuse the current thread instead of having it sit blocking...)

Comment: I don't understantd var fooTask = Task.Factory.StartNew( () => fooFunction() );
        var monitorTask = Task.Factory.StartNew( () => MonitoringThreadFunction() );

        Task.WaitAll(fooTask, monitorTask);
Could you explain it? Thank you!

Comment: @AndersLind Not sure why Join wouldn't work - but the Task option (and my improved Parallel.Invoke version) use the Task Parallel Library.  For details on Task, see: http://reedcopsey.com/2010/03/15/parallelism-in-net-part-13-introducing-the-task-class/  For Parallel.Invoke, see: http://reedcopsey.com/2010/02/26/parallelism-in-net-part-11-divide-and-conquer-via-parallel-invoke/

Comment: Out of curiosity why did you go with `Parallel.Invoke` inside a loop rather than just `Parallel.For`

Comment: @ConradFrix The OP wanted this to run "sequentially" - a Parallel.For would have run each of the 3 items in parallel, which was the opposite of what was asked...